# Activate virtualenv in windows

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I made a my project folder using `virtualenv project`
All are ok. But can not activate it.
Using `Scripts/activate` to activate but failed.

Comment: are you using PowerShell? If so, did you `PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`?